# Network Hangs during a Git checkout

Tags: networking, git

I have a local git configured in my server. People who are working, clones the git to their machine. Initially things were fine, Now when the size of data has increased, the Checkout causes the entire network of mine to hang, So I have to reset the router every other time. Has anyone come across this kinda issue?

NB: The git is a local one, so internet connection's speed doesn't come into consideration here.

Any Help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One can only guess in cases like this, but lets see if I can help.

Make sure your network don't have a [Layer 2 loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switching_loop) configured. Cheap HUBs will lock your network immediately if that happens, but some don't and the problem may pop up at random.

Sinse you are transferring locally, there is a chance your machines have chose automatically to use IPv6 to do that, and some HUBs don't digest IPv6 traffic very well. Try to disable IPv6 in your computers' network adapters and see if it brings any benefict.

If its of no use, you can debug your network traffic using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see what kind of [broadcast storm](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/B/broadcast_storm.html) is undergoing and what IP or MAC was responsible for it.

Comment: a big thanks for your inputs. I will check the IPV6 thing. And couldn't find anything suspicious in wireshark, lemme double check that. any other inputs?